# Writing a django view that does not return an object

Tags: python, django

I am writing a django view that just post some data and update a variable in the database. The view will not return anything as I am submitting the data using jquery-ajax.

I am getting the following error:

```
The view mysite.views.home didn't return an HttpResponse object
```

Again I do not wish to return an html page or anything of that sort. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
return HttpResponse("")
```

I usually do:

```
return HttpResponse("OK")
```

just because. In case I want to add error codes in later.

Answer (score 7):

A view in Django *must* return a `HttpResponse`, even if it's empty.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to return an HttpResponse, even for an Ajax query. If you're sure it doesn't need any content, you can return an empty one:

```
return HttpResponse('')
```

but I would at least put `'ok`' to indicate to your Javascript that everything went correctly.